# How to import a CSV file to a PostgreSQL table using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin

I am trying to import the following **csv file** (named dummy.csv):

"F1", "F2", "F3"

1,2,"a"

3,4, "b"

3.4,2.4,"c"

to **PostgreSQL** using the **pgAdmin GUI** with the following command:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\12\\bin\\psql.exe" 
--command " "\\copy public.\"Result\" 
FROM 'dummy.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' 
QUOTE '\"' 
ESCAPE '''';""
```

but keep getting the following **error**:

```
ERROR: extra data after the last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY Result, line 2: «1,2,"a"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The csv is not very 'clean':

```
"F1", "F2", "F3"

1,2,"a"

3,4, "b"

3.4,2.4,"c"
```

There are spaces between the separator and the quotes which could give problems with some parsers.

Maybe try with the following first and see what this gives:

```
"F1","F2","F3"
1,2,"a"
3,4,"b"
3.4,2.4,"c"
```

You could even remove the quotes in this example.

Comment: You are right Danny, there are a few white spaces. I followed your advices, removed the white spaces and also the quotes and still got the same message error that there are extra data after the last column (poiting at the first row with data).

Comment: @SergiJustinianoClaramunt What if you remove the last 3 lines of your command (CSV.., QUOTE.., ESCAPE..)?

Comment: I realised I needed to create the table specifieng which columns it would have beforehand, but this was a dummy example with only 3 columns, so I could do it manually.
The table that I originally tried to upload has over 1000 column, so I am wondering if there is any way I can automatize the process.
PD: thank you btw for your quick replies.